Autocomplection with description in zsh
General overview
This question complete this other one.
I try to set an autocomplete for --test parameter who should suggest a list of possible values (Here “foo” and “bar”). Until theire, it pretty work with “The list WITHOUT descrption” in the code bellow.
Now, I have to add to value a column containing a description of the value in front of it, with “The list WITH description” in the code bellow.
The Minimal Working Example
(( $+functions[_triumphum_parametter_values] )) ||
_triumphum_parametter_values() {

   # The list without spaces
  TMPLIST="Foo[Longdescription]
  Bar[Anotherlongdescription]"

   # The list WITH description
  TMPLIST="Foo[Long description]
  Bar[Another long description]"

   # The list WITHOUT description
  TMPLIST="Foo
  Bar"

  local allowedValues; allowedValues=($(echo $TMPLIST))
  if [ ${#allowedValues} -gt 0 ]; then
    _values -s , 'Available values' "${allowedValues[@]}"
  else
    _message 'Available values (none found)'
  fi
}

_triumphum_complete() {
_arguments \
  {-h,--help}'[show help options]' \
  --test'[This is a test parametter]: :_triumphum_parametter_values' \
}

compdef _triumphum_complete triumphum


The problem
So when I delete the “The list WITHOUT description” and try to autocomplete I get the rendering:
triumphum --test
_values:compvalues:11: invalid value definition: Foo[Long
_values:compvalues:11: invalid value definition: Foo[Long
_values:compvalues:11: invalid value definition: Foo[Long

But the problem doesn’t occure when the description betwean the brackets do not contain spaces (as example with “The list without spaces”):
triumphum --test
Available values
Bar  -- Anotherlongdescription
Foo  -- Longdescription

Furthermore, the problem does not appear with the _arguments auto-completion. Its only ocure with options values.
Where the problem seems located
So the problem seems related to space presence.
The question
So, how could I have auto completion also with option’s values ?

Can you assign to allowedValues directly like allowedValues=("Foo[Long description]" "Bar[Another long description]")? Or does TMPLIST come from somewhere else (for example, the output of some other command)?

Well, at a later state, the allowedValues will be set by another command. But in intermediate state I can’t just formate it with explicit and hardcoded values.

The main issue with $(echo "$TMPLIST") is that it splits on any whitespace, rather than just newlines. In zsh, you can split a variable on newlines with ${(@f)TMPLIST}, then use another layer of expansion to remove any leading spaces from each element:
_triumphum_parametter_values() {
   # The list without spaces
  TMPLIST="Foo[Longdescription]
  Bar[Anotherlongdescription]"

   # The list WITH description
  TMPLIST="Foo[Long description]
  Bar[Another long description]"

  local -a allowedValues
  # split on newlines, then remove leading spaces from each element
  allowedValues=("${(@)${(@f)TMPLIST}## #}")
  if [[ ${#allowedValues} -gt 0 ]]; then
    _values -s , 'Available values' "${allowedValues[@]}"
  else
    _message 'Available values (none found)'
  fi
}

